# What would happen dumping a pound of pepper into a Gust of Wind blowing down a hallway full of bad guys?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I recently cast Gust of Wind on a narrow bridge full of bad guys. I later remembered that I was packing a one pound bag of pepper. So I was wondering, if I had kept the Gust of Wind running (concentrating) till the next round, what effect might having dumped my pepper into the wind had on these guys? (Sneezing? Disadvantage on save? Blinded one round?) I can't find anything in the rules about pepper. Just wondering, if there are no rules on it, what would seem a reasonable effect to ask of the DM?

Comment: This looks opinion-based and likely to be put on hold. As is, there would be too many answers and all of them would be equally correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Reasonable things to ask the DM: Anything logical, rational or utterly hilarious**

Since the rules do not cover this, you're looking at an improvised attack/effect scenario. I for one think this is awesome and encourage people to do things just like this.

Possible effects I would allow if DM in this scenario: D/A on attacks, concentration check required for spells with verbal components, % chance to start sneezing.

Possible defenses against this for characters: You see a black wall of something being carried on the wind coming towards you so you elect to hold your breath and shield your eyes. Attempt to catch a lot of the pepper in a large pot to make steak au poivre later.

And so on.

Bottom line is: this is an improvised thing that isn't covered by the rules. While I hate seeing this answer here repeatedly, this entire scenario is in the hands of you and the DM.

Answer (score 3):

Look to what the rules do allow and extrapolate from there.

For 100gp you can buy Poison that does 1d4 damage on a failed DC10 save. Now you probably didn't pay that much and pepper isn't as toxic as poison so we need to dial this down a bit. So, probably not damage but hold onto the DC10 save.

Now *Stinking Cloud* is a third level spell which can debilitate those within on a failed save. This is pretty strong but then, it's a third level spell; not a bag of pepper. It also would be dispersed by a *Gust of Wind*. So, wind back (a lot) from here but note the dispersal.

So, you have an irritant in your nose and eyes? Sounds like *Poisoned* to me - disadvantage on attack rolls and ability checks. DC10 or poised for 1 round, pepper lasts until your next turn? Sounds OK to me.